# Error compiling HtmlViewer component for Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am trying the compile the HtmlViewer component for Delphi 7 (https://github.com/BerndGabriel/HtmlViewer). Opened the project Frameviewer7.dpk under package subdir

However I am getting the following compilation errors:
HtmlBuffer.pas(1611): Array Type required.

Which corresponds to the following code:

```
 if FStart.BytePtr[0] = 0
```

And FStart is defined as `FStart: TBuffPointer;`

```
TBuffPointer = record
    case Integer of
      0: (BytePtr: PByte;);
      1: (WordPtr: PWord;);
      2: (AnsiChr: PAnsiChar;);
      3: (WideChr: PWideChar;);
    end;
```

Not sure what is wrong here. My compiler is Delphi7

Comment: `FStart.BytePtr^ = 0` will probably work.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks that corrected the errors. If you add this as an answer I will accept. However not really sure about the difference between both syntaxes (my Delphi knowledge is very poor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FStart.BytePtr[0]` indicates that `FStart.BytePtr` is an *array*, and the value of this expression is the first (0th) element in this array.

However, `FStart.BytePtr` is actually a *pointer*. But often you can use arrays and pointers to achieve the same task -- either you use an array of `TSomeType`, or you use a pointer to the first element in an in-memory list of `TSomeType` items.

I assume this is what is going on here. Hence, you want to get the first item of a list of `byte` values, the first occurring at address `FStart.BytePtr`. To obtain the `byte` at this location, you dereference the pointer using `^`: `FStart.BytePtr^`.

The code you have found tries to access data using array notation on a pointer. This syntactic sugar might work in some newer version or Delphi, or using some compiler option. (I don't recall.)

Comment: For `PByte`, it will work in newer versions without a compiler option. For other types, it requires the `{$POINTERMATH ON}` option. Delphi 7 doesn't have this yet.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax uses a feature of later Delphi compilers that allows you to use indexed references for offsets from typed pointers.  In some versions of Delphi this requires the **POINTERMATH** compiler option or directive to be specified.

Unfortunately this is not supported in Delphi 7.

The typical way to work around this is to use an array type and declare a pointer to this array type.  The actual bounds of the array type are not important (in the sense that you will be using the pointer type so you will not be creating actual large array structures, only treating pointers as if they were references to such structures).

The only consideration is that the upper limit needs to be higher than or equal to the highest index you will require to specify in order to keep the compiler happy that any literal indexes you specify may be valid.

i.e. if you specified an array of only 100 items then any code that attempted to reference a 101st item would fail bounds checking either at compile time or runtime (if runtime checks are enabled).

So for a simple example we'll use an array of 65535 items:

```
const
  MAX_BYTEARRAYDIM = 65535;

type
  TByteArray = array[0..MAX_BYTEARRAYDIM] of Byte;
  PByteArray = ^TByteArray;


procedure SomeExampleMethod;
var
  pb: PByteArray;
begin
  // ..

  pb[12] := 25;  // The array type is 0 based so this sets the value of byte offset 12 bytes from the address in pb
end;
```

This has the advantage (should it be a concern in your code) of being portable to all versions of Delphi.

### Application in Your Case

In your specific case you could redefined the **BytePtr** type in this way.  Not being familiar with the *HTMLViewer* code I cannot say whether this may be practical.

An alternative would be to declare the necessary array and pointer types and to to typecast as and where required, e.g.:

```
if PByteArray(FStart.BytePtr)[0] = 0
```

Of course, the same technique can be applied to other pointer types as required.